# How to get names from linear predictor in r

Tags: r, dataframe, names

Evening,

I am trying to get the names to add to a data frame from an object of the following form

`regressors <- ~ log(Rate) + Weed + Monocot + Warm + Stage + Method`

I would like the individual regressor names, e.g. 
`c("log(Rate)", "Weed",...)` 
so I can use these in a data frame without having to manually do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vars <- as.character(regressors)[[2]]
names_vars <- strsplit(vars, "\\s\\+\\s")[[1]] # split at + preceded and followed by a space. 

## [1] "log(Rate)" "Weed"      "Monocot"   "Warm"      "Stage"     "Method"
```

`all.vars` function can come to rescue although it removes function names from variables such as `log` from `log(Rate)`.

```
all.vars(regressors)
[1] "Rate"    "Weed"    "Monocot" "Warm"    "Stage"   "Method"
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
attr(terms(regressors), "term.labels")
#> [1] "log(Rate)" "Weed"      "Monocot"   "Warm"      "Stage"     "Method"
```